# Can anyone recommend a good iOS / Android emulator?

Tags: sharepoint-online

We're approaching this a little backwards, I know.  It's a wonderful publishing site collection using standard pages for intranet, with functional yet attractive design, all rolled out a few months before Communication and/or News site options. Un-stallable timeline to use the better tools.

We have mobile viewing activated, and two super generic device channels (iOS and Android). I'm trying to evaluate where the mobile viewing pain points are for Apple and Android mobile and tablet devices, and would love to be able to view pages in a preview-as-tablet or preview-as-mobile manner.

Any suggestions?

*More info:*  Design has been done with responsive design and mobile viewing activated, but I think we all know the shortcomings there

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you ever tried Google Chrome's device toolbar? https://imgur.com/a/6TKF7

Comment: I had not - that' exactly what I was looking for!  Thank you

Comment: Yea you can try chrome's default toolbar because sharepoint pages most of the time needs responsive fixation using media query

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to [Sergey](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/7190/sergey) for the tip - 
Here's a URL for anyone else interested:

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode/emulate-mobile-viewports